# Python wx.notebook tab's controls - reading one from another

Tags: python, wxpython

Quick question: I have a python application with 3 tabs. Is it possible to read the state of a control on tab 2 from tab 1? That is, on tab 1 I have a run button. When clicking this I want to determine which checkboxes are checked on tab 2.

Should be quite simple, but I can't seem to suss it!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, yes. All the controls are usually private members of the `wxFrame` class. I don't really understand what is the problem.